# How to notify Grid when new object was added to model

Tags: java, web-applications, mvp, vaadin7

I'm looking way to notify multiple components when model value was change.
For example, I have got class UserForm which extends VerticalLayout and contains
form for adding new user. And second class UserDataGrid which extends Grid and it displays all users. Both of them use the same service UserService.

How Can I notify my UserDataGrid when UserForm add new user?

I invent to add UserDataGird as dependency of UserForm and in UserForm.addNewUser method, just update UserDataGrid. Is it good way?